How to distinguish active app now in tasks?
Under Kubuntu 22.04 I use the Breeze theme which distinguish the current window but I would like to distinguish it a bit more. Sometimes it is difficult for me to see which app is active in the tasks bar.

Can I tune it somehow ?
